# How to stop program without System.exit

Tags: java

Okay, I read somewhere that using the System.exit command is like cutting a watermelon with a saw.

I have this part of code and one exception inside it

```
   try {
        System.out.print("Add last name of passenger: ");//asking user to enter last name
        passenger.setLastName(scanner.nextLine());//scanning his input
        if (!passenger.getLastName().contains("[A-Za-z]")) {//if his input is not equal with this regex
           throw new NoNumbersException();//throw this
        }
    } catch (NoNumbersException nne) {
        System.out.println(nne.getMessage());//catch exception
        System.exit(0);//exit program
    }
```

How to stop this program by exception without `System.exit`? If I remove it from code program print me exception and then continue with other code, after that program save me input for last name even that is integer

Comment: Basically tell all threads to stop (e.g. with interrupting).

Answer (score 0):

Your program and the JVM it's being executed on automatically terminates when no more non-daemon threads are alive. You will have to gracefully stop all threads that were started in your application to make it terminate.